# Roblox studio Sound max distance not working

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to create a script so that when a part touches another it plays sound from a parent called speaker, I am trying and have set the max distance to 50 studs but it's not working

Here is the script:

```
local announce = game.Workspace.Announce
local vehicleSeat = game.Workspace["AXP Series(tong's mod)"].VehicleSeat
local speaker = game.Workspace.Speaker
local sound = game.SoundService.Sound

vehicleSeat.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
    if otherPart == announce then
        sound.Parent = speaker
        sound:Play()
    end
end)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foMYO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this DevForum conversation](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/help-with-audio-how-to-use-rolloff-max-and-min-distance/1079944/3), it sounds like you need to double check that the Sound is a child of a Part, not a Model. When the sound is Parented to a Model, you can hear the sound everywhere.

This is confirmed in the [Sound documentation](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Sound) :

> A sound placed in a BasePart or an Attachment will emit its sound from that part's BasePart.Position or the attachment's Attachment.WorldPosition
>
> ...
>
> A sound is considered "global" if it is not parented to a BasePart or an Attachment. In this case, the sound will play at the same volume throughout the entire place.